# variable in turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

Here is a simple turing machine, that accepts only $0$.

[image: tm accepts zero]

For this, it read $0$, write it with $x$, then move to right and checks end, if it is end it accepts.

With that logic, I can also add this `1->x,R`, then it accepts all strings of length 1, {'0','1'}.

[image: tm accepts strings of length 1]

What I want to do is, instead of writing to logic I want to write one, `$anything$ -> $another_thing$,R`.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Turing machine diagram is a form of communication. Its goal is to describe a Turing machine — usually defined as a tuple with a specific format — in a form which is easier to grasp. As such, you can use whatever shortcut you want, as long as everybody understands what you mean. This might entail your explaining some non-standard notation which you invented as shorthand.

Your professor might have different ideas about this, but the answer I gave is valid for the working mathematician.